# $location.path redirects to wrong location

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This function is called when a button is clicked on my web page.

```
$scope.go=function(takenAt){
    var path = '/oneMinuteMetric/loadCapturedMetrics?'+'&timestamp=' + takenAt + '&tagName='+ $stateParams.tagName;
    console.log(path);    //first
    $location.path(path);
    console.log($location.path());  //second            
};
```

But strangely when my page is redirected, the location is completely wrong.

The first `console.log` prints `/oneMinuteMetric/loadCapturedMetrics?&timestamp=1467976859092&tagName=TestTag`

and the second `console.log` also prints `/oneMinuteMetric/loadCapturedMetrics?&timestamp=1467976859092&tagName=TestTag`

whereas in my browser window the path is `/oneMinuteMetric/loadCapturedMetrics?tagName=TestTag&timestamp=1468143868308%2F%3FtagName%3DTestTag`

"`%2F%3FtagName%3DTestTag`" get appended on its own and then my request is rejected as bad request by the server. We have used this method for redirecting at several places but strangely it does not work here. Why?

**PS:** The location of my web page is `/oneMinuteMetric/tagHistory?tagName=TestTag`. This where the button is clicked and the given function is executed

**Solution:** $location.url(path) works in this case.

Comment: try this : location.href=path does it give you the same behaviour?

Comment: I just tested it with the path as `/oneMinuteMetric/loadCapturedMetrics?&timestamp=1467976859092&tagName=TestTag` and it is working fine for me.

Comment: you mean i need to replace  `$location.path(path);` with `window.location.href = path` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$location.search()` to add query parameters.

```
$location.path("/oneMinuteMetric/loadCapturedMetrics");
$location.search({'timestamp' : tokenAt, 'tagName' : $stateParams.tagName });
```

When you pass an **array** to `$location.search()` it will override the existing query parameter component.

In your case, the query parameter "%2F%3FtagName%3DTestTag" still exists from current url because `$location.path()` will only update the **path** and won't modify/override query parameter component.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. Your solution works! Although I went with $location.url(path).

Comment: This is helpful. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL

Answer (score 0):

`$location.url(path)` works in this case.